# How can i list the data of price next to title? ex: Pepsi Pepsi Max - 330Ml LBP 17,999

Tags: python, pandas, list, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

webpage = requests.get("https://www.spinneyslebanon.com/catalogsearch/result/?q=pepsi")

soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage.content, 'html.parser')

title = soup.find_all('a', 'product-item-link')

price = soup.find_all('span', 'price')

for i in title:

    simp1 = i.get_text()
    print(simp1)
for i in price:

    simp2 = i.get_text()
    print(simp2)
data = {

    'Name_of_item': simp1,
    'price_of_item': simp2
}

print(data)
```

output:

```
Pepsi Pepsi Max - 330Ml                            
                                                            Pepsi Regular Bottle 330ml                            

                                                            Pepsi Black Regular Bottle 330ml                            

                                                            Pepsi Diet Bottle 2.25L                            

                                                            Pepsi Regular 2.25L                            

                                                            Pepsi Regular Can 185ml                            

                                                            Pepsi Diet Bottle 1.25L                            

                                                            Pepsi Diet Can 185ml                            

                                                            Pepsi Regular Bottle 1.25L                            

                                                            Pepsi Diet Pet - 330Ml                            

                                                            Pepsi Can Diet 330ml                            

                                                            Pepsi Can 330ml                             

                                                            Aquafina Mineral Water Bottle 10x330ml + 2 FREE                            

                                                            Aquafina Mineral Water Gallon Pet - 6L                            
LBP 17,999
LBP 3,999
LBP 3,999
LBP 10,999
LBP 10,999
LBP 4,999
LBP 8,999
LBP 4,999
LBP 8,999
LBP 3,999
LBP 5,999
LBP 5,999
LBP 11,500
LBP 6,999
{'Name_of_item': '\n                            \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t \tAquafina Mineral Water Gallon Pet - 6L                            ', 'price_of_item': 'LBP 6,999'}
```

Comment: Can you clarify what output you want  or what error are you getting

Comment: @ArmenKaymakamian Please [edit] your question to include that information.

Comment: @ArmenKaymakamian And what's the _expected_ output? please include that also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) function to combine the "title" and "price" in order to print them together.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

webpage = requests.get("https://www.spinneyslebanon.com/catalogsearch/result/?q=pepsi")

soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage.content, 'html.parser')

title = soup.find_all('a', 'product-item-link')
price = soup.find_all('span', class_='price')

for t, p in zip(title, price):
    print("{:<60} {:<30}".format(t.get_text(strip=True), p.get_text(strip=True)))
```

Output:

```
Pepsi Pepsi Max - 330Ml                                      LBP 17,999                    
Pepsi Regular Bottle 330ml                                   LBP 3,999                     
Pepsi Black Regular Bottle 330ml                             LBP 3,999                     
Pepsi Diet Bottle 2.25L                                      LBP 10,999
```

The `{:<60} {:<30}` will align the characters to the left with the length of 60 and 30 to get a nicer formatting.

Comment: @ArmenKaymakamian I've included that as an explanation in my answer

Comment: @ArmenKaymakamian Um, I'm not sure what you mean

Comment: @ArmenKaymakamian Please note that it's one question per post on Stack Overflow, if you have another question, consider asking a new question on SO, as to not clutter the comment section. I'll see if I can take a look at that

Answer (score 0):

Here i have create `data` as dictionary and value as list of price and title for that as from your output you can simple print `price_list` and `title_list` as you wanted

```
import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

webpage = requests.get("https://www.spinneyslebanon.com/catalogsearch/result/?q=pepsi")

soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage.content, 'html.parser')

titles = soup.find_all('a', 'product-item-link')

prices = soup.find_all('span', 'price')

price_list=[price.get_text() for price in prices]
title_list=[title.get_text(strip=True) for title in titles]

data={}
data['Name_of_item']=title_list
data['price_of_item']=price_list
data
```

Ouput:

```
    {'Name_of_item': ['Pepsi Pepsi Max - 330Ml',
  'Pepsi Regular Bottle 330ml',
  'Pepsi Black Regular Bottle 330ml',
  'Pepsi Diet Bottle 2.25L',
  'Pepsi Regular 2.25L',
  'Pepsi Regular Can 185ml',
  'Pepsi Diet Bottle 1.25L',
  'Pepsi Diet Can 185ml',
  'Pepsi Regular Bottle 1.25L',
  'Pepsi Diet Pet - 330Ml',
  'Pepsi Can Diet 330ml',
  'Pepsi Can 330ml',
  'Aquafina Mineral Water Bottle 10x330ml + 2 FREE',
  'Aquafina Mineral Water Gallon Pet - 6L'],
 'price_of_item': ['LBP 17,999',
  'LBP 3,999',
  'LBP 3,999',
  'LBP 10,999',
  'LBP 10,999',
  'LBP 4,999',
  'LBP 8,999',
  'LBP 4,999',
  'LBP 8,999',
  'LBP 3,999',
  'LBP 5,999',
  'LBP 5,999',
  'LBP 11,500',
  'LBP 6,999']}
```